# show div boxes when buttons are clicked

Tags: jquery, button

Still getting my head around the code here. I'd like to be able to show a series of 'answers' when questions are clicked. The questions are buttons, and the answers are divs. Any help would be gratefully received.

```
<h4 class="JCU-title">
<button  onclick="javascript:showDiv(answer1);">The</button>
<button  onclick="javascript:showDiv(answer2);">girl</button>
<button  onclick="javascript:showDiv(answer3);">plays</button>
<button  onclick="javascript:showDiv(answer4);">soccer</button>
</h4>

<!--show (toggle?) only one answer div box at a time-->
<div id="answer0">blank</div>
<div id="answer1">the is a determiner</div>
<div id="answer2">girl is a common noun </div>
<div id="answer3">play is a verb.</div>
<div id="answer4">Soccer common noun.</div>
```

Comment: And what you've tried so far??

Comment: Where's your `showDiv()` function code? And why are using `javascript:showDiv(...)` where it could simply be `showDiv(...)`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function showDiv(id){ 
  $(".answer").hide();
  $("#"+id).show();
}
```

```css
.answer{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="JCU-title">
<button  onclick="showDiv('answer1');">The</button>
<button  onclick="showDiv('answer2');">girl</button>
<button  onclick="showDiv('answer3');">plays</button>
<button  onclick="showDiv('answer4');">soccer</button>
</h4>

<!--show (toggle?) only one answer div box at a time-->
<div id="answer0" class="answer">blank</div>
<div id="answer1" class="answer">the is a determiner</div>
<div id="answer2" class="answer">girl is a common noun </div>
<div id="answer3" class="answer">play is a verb.</div>
<div id="answer4" class="answer">Soccer common noun.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sinha, that's great.